# Subtraction with doubles returning zero erroneously

Tags: teensy

I have a function that takes as parameter some doubles and does a subtraction operation on it. However I'm getting a result of 0 when one of the parameter is 0 for some reason.

```
int calcPID(double current, double desired, double k){
  double diff;
  diff = desired - current;
  Serial.print("desired = ");
  Serial.print(desired);
  Serial.print(", current = ");
  Serial.print(current);
  Serial.print(", diff = ");
  Serial.println(diff);
  int r = (int)diff;
  return r;
}
```

Output

```
desired = 250.00, current = 1.69, diff = 248.31
desired = 250.00, current = 0.00, diff = 0.00
```

When the current is 0.00 the result (diff) is also 0.00, when it should be 250. Can someone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce that.

```c++
int calcPID(double current, double desired, double k) {
  double diff;
  diff = desired - current;
  Serial.print("desired = ");
  Serial.print(desired);
  Serial.print(", current = ");
  Serial.print(current);
  Serial.print(", diff = ");
  Serial.println(diff);
  int r = (int)diff;
  return r;
}

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();
  calcPID (1.69, 250, 42);
  calcPID (0, 250, 42);
}  // end of setup

void loop ()
{
}  // end of loop
```

That gives expected output of:

```
desired = 250.00, current = 1.69, diff = 248.31
desired = 250.00, current = 0.00, diff = 250.00
```

I strongly suspect you are passing NaN (not a number) or Inf (infinity) instead of zero. If you add another test line like this:

```c++
 calcPID (1.0 / 0, 250, 42);
```

Then you get the result:

```
desired = 250.00, current = inf, diff = inf
```

Now I know you reported getting zero, but earlier versions of the IDE printed 0 for NaN or Inf. I suggested a change to the way the libraries handle that which has been implemented in more recent versions.

[Here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/961), for example.

---

If this doesn't answer your question, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - like I did above.

Comment: I think NaN is probably it because when I compare current > 1 and current <= 1 both came out to false.

Comment: dang it i was such a poopoohead before now i get it thnx

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing the input values in the correct type:

```
calcPID(0.00, 250, 0.0);
```

will return 0, while

```
calcPID(0.00, 250.0, 0.0);
```

will return 250

**UPDATE**

[Here you can get a working test case](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQjc0QlhMQ1g5d0E): it's running on a different processor, so don't expect to behave exactly as the 8bit MCU at Arduino's core.

Comment: Is this based on a test, or a source-code reading, or what?  What's the name of the library .cpp and .h files you looked at?  How do you account for implicit type conversion not occurring?

Comment: @jwpat7 I didn't look at any library, I just looked at the above code and the only viable option I was able to find is if the OP is expecting type conversion to occur in C as if it was Java. When I posted my answer there was only the `calcPID` function reported, but now, looking at the updated example I'm more convinced about my answer, so much I updated it with a test.

Answer (score 1):

@Roberto Lo Giacco The difference is, that on Arduino (IDE) are headers for *.ino done before standard C++ compilation

```
#include <stdio.h> // on *.ino it is done in IDE hidden way
int calcPID(double current, double desired, double k) ; // forward definition, for *.ino it is done in Arduino IDE hidden way
int main()
{
    calcPID (1.69, 250, 42);
    calcPID (0, 250, 42);
    calcPID (0.0, 250.0, 42);
    return 0;
}

int calcPID(double current, double desired, double k) {
  double diff;
  diff = desired - current;
  printf("desired = %5.2f, current = %5.2f, diff = %5.2f, true = %i\n", desired, current, diff, diff > 0);
  int r = (int)diff;
  printf("desired = %5.2f, current = %5.2f, diff = %i, true = %i\n", desired, current, r, r > 0);
  return r;
}
```

This compiles and executes on your machine well a gives correct result same as @Nick Gammon have.

Without the definition `int calcPID(double current, double desired, double k) ;` standard C assumes definition with `ints` and makes different conversions, which leads to your "incorrect" result. So the result depends on forward definition, which Arduino does behind scene. But for *.cpp and *.h it may be different, so it would be interesting, how `bakalolo` organized his code.